# Bloch functions at the bottom of the band are complete with respect to periodic functions, how?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I am reading this landmark paper by [Luttinger and Kohn](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.97.869). In the paper, instead of directly using the Bloch functions or the Wannier fucntions (fourier transform of Bloch functions) as basis functions, the authors define a new basis.(See attached image)

They give a brief proof that if Bloch functions form a complete set, then the newly defined basis functions are also complete. In the proof, they make the following statement: 'Any periodic function can be expanded in terms of Bloch functions at the bottom of the band'. I am unable to wrap my head around this. How does one prove this assertion ? [image]

Additional thoughts:
The complete space of Bloch function space (defined by eigen-functions in II.3) is comprised of the functions at all k and all n. Now consider a subset of this space defined at all n but only at k=0, the center of the First Brillouin Zone. Each function in this subspace has the e^ikr factor become 1. So, the bloch functions in this subspace are just given by u_n0. These are just functions periodic in K, the reciprocal lattice vectors. Now the question becomes, can any other function periodic in K, say u_nk be expressed as linear combinations of n other functions u_n0 periodic in K ? Intuitively, if we assume n goes to infinity, we have n periodic functions which are ortho-normal (because the Bloch functions are ON). So, they span the same space formed by the basis e^(iK.r). So, same space different eigen-basis. (I guess this answers the question)